# Почему не на всех устройствах проходят звонки если сим карта во 2 слоте и она одна?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте!

Написал приложение для `Android`, которое при нажатии на определенную кнопку осуществляет звонок через стандартную "звонилку".  Вызывая событие `android.intent.action.CALL`. 
Тестирую на устройствах с двумя сим картами. Если в 1 слоте звонки проходят на всех устройствах.

Если сим карта во 2 слоте (вставляю только одну сим карту) результат:

Планшет `"Dream" Android 4.1` звонки проходят с обоих слотов.

Телефон "`Huawei G525" Android 4.1` со 2 слота при нажатии кнопки вызова в программе, приложение рушится

```
07-08 06:43:15.149 W/System.err( 1634):         at com.tess01.spravka01.SpravkaActivity$9.onItemClick(SpravkaActivity.java:523)

07-08 06:43:15.149 W/System.err( 1634):         at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)

07-08 06:43:15.149 W/System.err( 1634):         at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)

07-08 06:43:15.149 W/System.err( 1634):         at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2859)
```

Телефон "`Android" Android 2.2` если сим карта во 2 слоте приложение не видит сим карту.

В чем может быть проблема невозможности звонить со 2 слота если сим карта одна?

Comment: Приведите полный стэктрэйс.

Comment: похоже, что крешится в самой программе. Интересно увидеть само исключение, а не только отрывок стектрейса. А также окрестности 523 строки файла SpravkaActivity.java